# How to read a file containing text and integers and save the integers in an array list

Tags: java, java-8

I have a text file, which I have called read_me2 ([link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/z4lmj9grnlcg9oe/read_me2.txt?dl=0)):

```
!This is for testing the ability to read a file
1 3 
4 5
6 7
8 9
1
2
3
4
5 6 4
```

I want to read it and store the data in a List of integers using Java 8 features. So far I was able to do it but in a way I believe is suboptimal. Can you give me some help. Below, please find my code:

```
    //This is my package
    package ReadAFile;

        // Modified http://www.mkyong.com/java8/java-8-stream-read-a-file-line-by-line/

        import java.io.IOException;
        import java.nio.file.Files;
        import java.nio.file.Paths;
        import java.util.ArrayList;
        import java.util.List;
        import java.util.stream.Collectors;
        import java.util.stream.Stream;


        public class ReadAndStoreFileContents {

            public static void main(String[] args) {

                List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<>(); 

String fileName2 = "/Users/riccardo/Dropbox/A-Data/JavaSandBox/read_me2.txt";   
                try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(fileName2))) {
                    list2 = stream.
                            filter(line -> !line.startsWith("!")).
                            collect(Collectors.toList());
                } catch (IOException e) { 
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


    //          This will be certainly not optimal because I m reading the List a second time           

                List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<>();  

                for(String string : list2){
                    for(String retval: string.split(" ")){
                        intList.add(Integer.valueOf(retval));
                    }
                    System.out.println(intList.toString());
                }


            }

        }
```

Thank you for your time,

riccardo

Comment: This question is better suited for code review: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a `Stream` of strings coming out of the file, you can flat-map them to single strings and then map them to `Integers`, and collect and print that:

```
try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(fileName2))) {
                        list2 = stream
                                .filter(line -> !line.startsWith("!"))
                                .flatMap(line -> line.split(" ").stream())
                                .map(Integer::valueOf)
                                .collect(Collectors.toList());
                    } catch (IOException e) { 
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

Comment: `split` returns an array, so you can’t call `stream()` on the result. You have to use either: `.flatMap(Pattern.compile(" ")::splitAsStream)` or `.flatMap(line -> Arrays.stream(line.split(" ")))`